# Submit form with partial data for updating rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm working with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core.
This is the definition of my table:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

In a Page I show only some fields, i.e.:

```
<form method="post">
    <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 400px;">
        <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Orders[0].Number)
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Orders[0].Quantity)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Orders)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
                        </th>
                        <td scope="row">
                            <input type="number" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)" asp-for="Order.Quantity"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="@Resources.Save" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

and here the cs code:

```
[BindProperty]
public Order Order { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.Orders.Attach(Order).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        throw new System.Exception($"Order {Order.Id} not found!");
    }
    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

but I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'Id' on entity type 'Order' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Modified'. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

**After some researches** it seems this means EF is waiting for an explicitly set of the Id fields, because the temporary key generated cannot be stored into the database.

But:

1. my primary key (Id) is int, so it should generate automatically
2. most important, I'm updating an *existing* record, the Id is already present in the database.

Is this due to the partial data I submitted? I don't want to show all the fields to the users, nor it seems a good idea to put data in hidden fields.

Comment: the error is telling you what the problem is. do a Google search on the exact error and you will find many examples explaining what this is and how to fix it.

Comment: I did, but I didn't understand. I apologize for that.

Comment: I mean, when I added the records I didn't set the Id, but it was created (1,2, 3, 4). It's unclear to me why now I have to set it again.

Comment: When you debug, is the `Id` filled in the Controller? I don't see where you are passing the Id back to the Controller from the View

Comment: I don't pass it because I don't display it in the form. Only the "Quantity" field (in the example) is passed back as this is the only field I need to update.

Comment: By the way, I cannot "pass" one Id, because as you can see the form shows multiple lines. The user will fill-in the quantities and I want to update only those fields in my table.

Answer (score 0):

You want to retrieve a list of records, so you have to bind according:

```
[BindProperty]
public List<Order> ListOrders { get; set; }
```

then in the View, use a for loop instead of a foreach, so you have an index:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Orders.Count; i++)
{
    ...
    <tr>
        <td scope="row">
            <input asp-for="ListOrders[i].Quantity" value="@Model.Orders[i].Quantity" readonly />
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately you have to put into the form all the fields (even if hidden).